# How to write a generative update in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm just using SQLAlchemy core, and cannot get the sql to allow me to add where clauses.  I would like this very generic update code to work on all my tables.  The intent is that this is part of a generic insert/update function that corresponds to every table.  By doing it this way it allows for extremely brief test code and simple CLI utilities that can simply pass all args & options without the complexity of separate sub-commands for each table.

It'll take a few more tweaks to get it there, but should be doing the updates now just fine.  However, while SQLAlchemy refers to generative queries it doesn't distinguish between selects & updates.  I've reviewed SQLAlchemy documentation, Essential SQLAlchemy, stackoverflow, and several source code repositories, and have found nothing.

```
u      = self._table.update()
non_key_kw = {}
for column in self._table.c:
    if column.name in self._table.primary_key:
        u.where(self._table.c[column.name] == kw[column.name])
    else:
        col_name = column.name
        non_key_kw[column.name] = kw[column.name]

print u
result = u.execute(kw)
```

Which fails - it doesn't seem to recognize the where clause:

```
UPDATE struct SET year=?, month=?, day=?, distance=?, speed=?, slope=?, temp=?
FAIL
```

And I can't find any examples of building up an update in this way.  Any recommendations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the "where()" method is generative in that it returns a new `Update()` object. The old one is not modified:

```
u = u.where(...)
```

Comment: Thanks - that worked perfect.   I guess I'm glad it was a stupid mistake on my part rather than a bug in a good tool. :-)